# Avro version incompatabilites

Tags: storage, avro, file-format, datastore

I can't find much info about file compatabilities/incompatabilities between Avro files serialized with different versions of the Apache or other Avro libraries.

I would like to know if Avro is a suitable long time storage format for original data or not?

Comment: Do you have an example of what versions you are concerned about? Avro has a relatively long history, and schema evolution with it would be better than storing data in JSON or other plaintext

Comment: Lets say I store alot of data with the 1.8.2 specification and later on it evolves to 1.9.3. Are all specification changes backwards compatible or will I have to handle different versions of all the libraries and tools depending on wich specification version the tool I used for serialization at a particular time?

Comment: I doubt there will be a breaking change until Avro 2.x (which isn't on a roadmap). Hence the semantic versioning... No matter what format you chose, I feel like your concern will always hold... 8-track tapes became cassettes, then CDs, then MP3s, now streams...

Comment: Thanks, ought to be safe to use for storage then.